# vue-typer component error when installing and registration

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, single-page-application, babel-loader

I'm working on a SPA website and I'm trying to use this component https://github.com/cngu/vue-typer but I got errors when installing and using it. 
Just a note, I used `npm install --save vue-typer` to install the component.

This is my code:

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'
import VueTyperPlugin from 'vue-typer'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueTyperPlugin)


let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: new VueRouter(routes)
});
```

**routes.js** (this is where I import all the components and set the routes)

```
import Home from './components/Home'
import Biografia from './components/Biografia'

export default {

    mode: 'history',

    linkActiveClass: 'font-bold',

    routes: [

        {
            path: '/',
            component: Home
        },

        {
            path: '/biografia',
            component: Biografia
        },

    ]
};
```

**Home.vue**  (one of the components)

```
<template>
<div>
    <vue-typer text='Hello World! I was registered locally!'></vue-typer>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        components: {
            VueTyper
        },
    }
</script>
```

**The error I get is this one:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: VueTyper is not defined
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:2077)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Module../resources/js/components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:20508)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Module../resources/js/components/Home.vue (app.js:20472)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Module../resources/js/routes.js (app.js:21180)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:20305)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed the instructions..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import VueTyper in your Home.vue component. Because when you request it in the components object it doesn't know what 'VueTyper' is.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by reinstalling the package, just by doing "npm install --save vue-typer".

That's strange, I'm sure I already did that before.